# Select on named pipe (FIFO) causes infinite loop

Tags: c, select, file-descriptor

I have a loop. Inside this loop I am trying to detect if a read or write is triggered on a named pipe (FIFO) file by using `select()`.

If a read is triggered I call `read()` on the FIFO file descriptor.
If a write is triggered I call `write()` on the FIFO file descriptor.

The issue is that if a write occurs and I write to the FIFO, it will trigger a read. And then when I read from the FIFO it will trigger a write. Causing an infinite loop.

This loop occurs immediately if I use the same file descriptor in mode `O_RDWR`. This loop occurs after the first write if I create a separate file descriptor for both reading and writing.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    // Open export fifo
    int fd = open("./foo-fifo", O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
    if (fd < 0) { // Failed to open
        perror("error opening fifo");
    }

    // Read or write fifo until "quit" is in buffer 
    while (true) {
        fd_set read_fds;
        fd_set write_fds;

        FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
        FD_SET(fd, &read_fds);

        FD_ZERO(&write_fds);
        FD_SET(fd, &write_fds);

        int num_fds = select(fd+1, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, NULL);
        if (num_fds < 0) { // Failed to select
            perror("failed to select fifo fd");
        } else if (num_fds == 0) { // Timeout
            continue;
        }

        // If read
        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &read_fds)) {
            char buf[1000] = "";

            if (read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)) < 0) {
                perror("error reading fifo");
            }

            printf("read: \"%s\"\n", buf);

            if (strcmp(buf, "quit\n") == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // If write
        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &write_fds)) {
            char *buf = "foo";

            if (write(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)) < 0) {
                perror("error writing fifo");
            }

            printf("write: \"%s\"\n", buf);
        }
    }

    // Close fifo
    if (close(fd) < 0) { // Failed to close
        perror("failed to close export fifo");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Run the example by downloading the code [from here (GitHub Gist)](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Noah-Huppert/08d51d54e28a774d6896de99942d94e9/raw/455994590551a396ccc5c340824194dc4ca09f74/fifo.c). Then run:

```
gcc -o fifo fifo.c
./fifo
```

The output will show a loop between reading and writing:

```
write: "foo"
read: ""
write: "foo"
read: ""
write: "foo"
...
```

Comment: There is no place in your code where you _write_ `quit`, so I would expect it to loop infinitely (e.g. you only write `foo`). Under what conditions do you want to write `quit` (e.g. after the Nth write message)?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: You don't normally open a FIFO for reading and writing in a single process.  A given process is either reading from or writing to the FIFO.  There is a problem with your design, I think — you've got an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) in some shape or form and we don't know what X is, so Y seems kinda weird, if not outrageous.

Comment: @Craig Estey Another external process would write `quit`

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler My intention was to make it possible for this process to handle other processes reading and writing to and from the FIFO. It sounds like I made some incorrect assumptions about how FIFO files work.

Comment: As Jonathan pointed out, we need a second process. So, we can't help with the debugging unless you can post the code for that process. Also, fifos are single direction (a writer and a reader), _not_ like a socket. So, to do this with fifos, you'll need _two_ of them. (e.g.) Given processes `A` and `B`, we need two pipes/fifos: `pipeAB` and `pipeBA`. Process `A` writes to `pipeAB` and `B` reads from `pipeAB`. Process `B` writes to `pipeBA` and `A` reads from `pipeBA`

Comment: @n.m. this example is supposed to print out messages sent to the FIFO, by other processes, and write `foo` to the queue if another process tries to read from it.

Comment: @Craig Estey thanks for clarifying FIFO file behavior. It sounds like I do want something more like a socket. For debugging I was just echo-ing and cat-ing the `foo-fifo` file from bash. However if you just run the example code it will exhibit the loop behavior even without another process.

Comment: If you want to use a socket, you could do a `PF_UNIX` (aka `AF_UNIX`) socket. See `man 7 unix` and `man 2 socketpair`. Or, you could do a full blown `AF_INET` socket with the host set to `localhost` with some fixed port number. As an exercise [for you], consider doing it in several ways. That is, an `argv` option like `-Tp` for dual pipes, `-Tu` for `AF_UNIX`, and `-Ts` for `AF_INET`, etc. Only the initialization would be different. The protocol would be nearly identical otherwise.

Comment: @CraigEstey Thank you for all your help understanding FIFO queues and sockets. If you'd like you could create an answer.

Comment: You may also want to use two named pipes.

Comment: @n.m. thanks for the suggestion. However for other reasons I'm trying to use 1 file

Comment: Then you need a socket, and a client/server role separation.

Answer (score 1):

*Note:* This is prefaced by my top comments.

We need two processes (e.g. a server and a client).

fifos are single direction (a writer and a reader), *not* like a socket.

So, to do this with fifos, you'll need two of them. (e.g.) Given processes A and B, we need two pipes/fifos: `pipeAB` and `pipeBA`.

Process A writes to `pipeAB` and B reads from `pipeAB`.

Process B writes to `pipeBA` and A reads from `pipeBA`

If you want to use a socket, you could do a `PF_UNIX` (aka `AF_UNIX`) socket. See `man 7 unix` and `man 2 socketpair`.

Or, you could do a full blown AF_INET socket with the host set to localhost with some fixed port number.

As an exercise [for you], consider doing it in several ways. That is, an `argv` option like `-Tp` for dual pipes, `-Tu` for AF_UNIX, and `-Ts` for AF_INET, etc. Only the initialization would be different. The protocol would be nearly identical otherwise.

For `AF_UNIX` sockets, if the client and server are different programs, it may be easier to create a file of type socket in the file system. This can be done by filling in a `struct sockaddr_un` with the "filename" and then using `bind` after the `socket` call. See: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.13/gtpc1/unixsock.html for an example